# Where can I find the Microsoft .NET Framework Development Guide?

Tags: .net, msdn

I'm positive that this guide existed, but my Google skills seem to be broken today. Could you show me the link to the MSDN pointing to that section?

Comment: Not deleting yet as others may have the same kind of acute google-disablement. If this question is considered useless, I'll just delete it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you figured out yourself, the article you were originally looking for is called [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) on the MSDN.

Note that it also exists a great complete book on the very same topic, named [Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613). Actually, the  MSDN page encourages you to have a look at this book if you want to go deeper:

> For more information on design
>   guidelines, see the "Framework Design
>   Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and
>   Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries"
>   book by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad
>   Abrams, published by Addison-Wesley,
>   2005.

[image]
<sub>(source: [davesbox.com](http://davesbox.com/images/books/FrameworkDesignGuidelines2ndEditionLarge.jpg))</sub>

Comment: What is the relationship between the topic in the MSDN and this book?

Comment: The relationship? Well the topic is the same, authors are likely the same. The article on the MSDN is a light version of the book. Many portions of the MSDN article come from the book actually.

Comment: So basically it's a must-read for any serious developer.

Comment: I'll gladly accept this answer if you add the link found in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's called "Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries" and can be found [here in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx)